# How do i display current user info on a page of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the name or any other info of users on their profile page. I'm using this simple code:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>

<html>
<body>
<p>Email: <?php echo $current_user->user_email; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But all my site displays is the following:

Email: user_email; ?>

How do i fix this to display their email?

Comment: Where is this code written? It is PHP and WordPress editor is only for HTML usually

Comment: If you `<?php print_r($current_user); ?>` what does it show?

Comment: Your code should display the email address of the current user. There might be some other issues causing this problem. In which file you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: _"But all my site displays is the following:"_ - that's what you would get, when that code gets passed to the browser _unparsed_ - so apparently you have not put this into a context where PHP gets parsed & executed in the first place.